# Ruby regex selecting multiple words at the same time

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a hash that I am using regex on to select what key/value pairs I want. Here is the method I have written:

```
def extract_gender_race_totals(gender, race)
  totals = @data.select {|k,v| k.to_s.match(/(#{gender})(#{race})/)}
  temp = 0
  totals.each {|key, value| temp += value}
  temp
end
```

the hash looks like this:

```
 @data = {
:number_of_african_male_senior_managers=>2,
:number_of_coloured_male_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_indian_male_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_white_male_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_african_female_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_coloured_female_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_indian_female_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_white_female_senior_managers=>0,
:number_of_african_male_middle_managers=>2,
:number_of_coloured_male_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_indian_male_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_white_male_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_african_female_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_coloured_female_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_indian_female_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_white_female_middle_managers=>0,
:number_of_african_male_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_coloured_male_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_indian_male_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_white_male_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_african_female_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_coloured_female_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_indian_female_junior_managers=>0,
:number_of_white_female_junior_managers=>0
}
```

but it's re-populated with data after a SQL Query.

I would like to make it so that the key must contain both the race and the gender in order for it to return something. Otherwise it must return 0. Is this right or is the regex syntax off?

It's returning 0 for all, which it shouldn't.

So the example would be

```
   %td.total_cell= @ee_demographics_presenter.extract_gender_race_totals("male","african")
```

This would return 4, there are 4 African, male managers.

Comment: Type here the example of input and wanted result.

Comment: does that help a little?

Comment: When trying to come up with regexes, I suggest checking http://www.rubular.com/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
def extract_gender_race_totals(gender, race)
  @data.select{|k, v| k.to_s.match(/#{race}_#{gender}/)}.values.reduce(:+)
end

extract_gender_race_totals("male", "african")
# => 4
```

Answer (score 4):

[gmalete's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929772/gmalette) answer gives an elegant solution, but here is just an explanation of why your regexp isn't quite right. If you corrected the regexp I think your approach *would* work, it just isn't as idiomatic Ruby.

`/(#{gender})(#{race})/` won't match number_of_african_male_senior_managers for 2 reasons:

1) the race comes before the gender in the hash key and 2) there is an underscore in the hash key that needs to be in the regexp. e.g.

```
/(#{race})_(#{gender})/
```

would work, but the parentheses aren't needed so this can be simplified to

```
/#{race}_#{gender}/
```

Comment: thanks for the help i can see where you are coming from! its my first time working with regex so its a learnign curve

Comment: No problems, you were pretty close for a first go!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having specific methods to query pieces of your keys (i.e. "gender_race"), you could make a general method to query any attribute in any order:

```
def extract_totals(*keywords)
  keywords.inject(@data) { |memo, keyword| memo.select { |k, v| k.to_s =~ /_#{keyword}(?:_|\b)/ } }.values.reduce(:+)
end
```

Usage:

```
extract_totals("senior")
extract_totals("male", "african")
extract_totals("managers") # maybe you'll have _employees later...
# etc.
```

Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it will help.